# Travel to EU with silencer in checked baggage

Tags: usa, paperwork, eu, permits

What are the rules for travel from the USA to the EU with a silencer in checked baggage?

What documents must be presented in the USA and on entering the EU?

Comment: Firearms regulation varies by member state, it is not an EU competency. We need to know which countries you're entering or travelling through.

Comment: By "silencer", do you mean a suppressor for a firearm or what Americans would call a muffler for a motor vehicle?

Comment: Or even a [DNA sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silencer_(genetics))?  Voting to close as "unclear".  Please edit your question to clarify what kind of "silencer" you mean, and it can be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

I'm asuming you talk about a silencer for a "real" firearm and not an air gun or the like. As Calchas pointed out, national laws apply. Europe has no constitutional right to carry and bear arms, a permit is required for each weapon.

In Germany silencers require a permit similar to a firearms permit, which would be extremely hard to get since the law recognizes few legitimate uses. ISTR that pest control on cemeteries are one exception. (A sports shooter can have a legitimate use for a .45 or 9mm, but never for a *silenced* 9mm.)